# Taking in optional boolean flags in a macro without expl3

Tags: macros, optional-arguments, key-value, parameters

I want to create a macro `\verticalStep` which will produce a vertical skip of fixed length, and take two optional arguments, `negative` and `small`.

So for you could use

- `\verticalStep` for a standard vertical skip
- `\VerticalStep[negative]` for reducing vertical skip by standard length
- `\verticalStep[small]` for a small fixed vertical skip
- `\VerticalStep[negative, small]` for reducing vertical skip by small standard length

I have been looking into `xkeyval` and `pgfkeys` and could not for the life of me find a simple or straightforward example of how I may go about parsing the argument and checking for the options. I managed to find [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/444146/define-command-macro-with-boolean-flag), but the only answer uses expl3 and I wonder if there is a more elegant solution that does not require switching syntax

Comment: What about using Lua?

Comment: Looks like the xkeyval package does have `define@boolkey`, but examples on the site are sparse e.g. [macros - How to define a key=value that has an equivalent boolean value key - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-to-define-a-key-value-that-has-an-equivalent-boolean-value-key/53602#53602).

Comment: Maybe understand the example in [macros - How to create a command with key values? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34312/how-to-create-a-command-with-key-values/34314#34314) first. For `keyval`, you just need to give some default argument to allow omitting the value (see texdoc keyval)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `pgfkeys`. The `.is if` handler allows one to easily connect PGF keys to `\iffoobar` TeX boolean switches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifmy@verticalStep@small           % initially false
\newif\ifmy@verticalStep@negative        % initially false

\pgfkeys{
  /my@verticalStep/options/.cd,
  small/.is if=my@verticalStep@small,
  negative/.is if=my@verticalStep@negative,
}

\NewDocumentCommand \verticalStep { O{} }
  {%
    \begingroup
    \pgfkeys{/my@verticalStep/options/.cd, #1}%
    %
    \par                        % my choice
    \vspace{%
      \ifmy@verticalStep@negative -\fi
      \ifmy@verticalStep@small \smallskipamount \else \bigskipamount \fi
    }%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

Normal:\verticalStep
Small:\verticalStep[small]

Negative:\verticalStep[negative]
% The negative skip we just did rewound exactly one line here, because
% \baselineskip and \bigskipamount have the same natural “width” (12pt), and
% the natural width of \parskip is 0pt. That's why I do this \hspace*{4.5em},
% otherwise “Negative” would be overprinted.
\hspace*{4.5em}Negative and small:\verticalStep[negative, small]
The end.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simple macros like these can be created with `expkv-cs` quite comfortably.

The `\ekvcSplit` macro sets up a command that takes one mandatory argument (hence we use a `\NewDocumentCommand`-defined wrapper for the optional argument), and splits it into separate arguments in the order of the defined primary keys, so that you can use `#1` for the first key in the definition. Additional keys that don't correspond to arguments directly can be set up using `\ekvcSecondaryKeys` (which we can use to set up your flag-like keys, which will then just forward specific values to your underlying keys).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\makeatletter
% grabbing argument as an optional argument
\NewDocumentCommand\VerticalStep{O{}}{\VerticalStep@{#1}}
\ekvcSplit\VerticalStep@
  {
     length = 0pt % value doesn't matter, will be set by ekvcChange
    ,sign = {} % empty for positive, else -
    ,star = {}
  }{\vspace#3{#2#1}}
\ekvcSecondaryKeys\VerticalStep@
  {
     nmeta negative = {sign=-}
    ,nmeta small = {length=1cm}
    ,nmeta standard = {length=2cm}
    ,nmeta force = {star=*}
  }
\ekvcChange\VerticalStep@{standard}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\VerticalStep

def
\VerticalStep[negative]

ghi
\VerticalStep[small,negative]

jkl
\VerticalStep[length=5cm]% arbitrary sizes also possible

mno
\end{document}
```

---

Another solution using a more traditional key=value interface as provided by `expkv-def`. This uses a skip-register to store the length, the `standard` and `small` keys change the length in that register, and the `negative`-key works as a Boolean (so can be set true or false).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv-def}
\makeatletter
\ekvdefinekeys{VerticalStep}
  {
     skip    length   = \VerticalStep@length
    ,nmeta   standard = {length = 2cm}
    ,initial standard
    ,nmeta   small    = {length = 1cm}
    ,boolTF  negative = \VerticalStep@negative
  }
\ekvsetdef\VerticalStepSetup{VerticalStep}
\NewDocumentCommand\VerticalStep{O{}}
  {%
    \begingroup
      \VerticalStepSetup{#1}%
      \vspace{\VerticalStep@negative{-}{}\VerticalStep@length}%
    \endgroup
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\VerticalStep

def
\VerticalStep[negative]

ghi
\VerticalStep[small,negative]

jkl
\VerticalStep[length=5cm]% arbitrary sizes also possible

mno
\end{document}
```

---

Outputs of both look identical:

[image]